# Dependence wso2 application in $PATH/repository/components/lib/

Tags: jar, dependencies, wso2

I paste one jar in repository/components/lib/ as dependence, but the wso2app does not find it when accessing the service, it throws the exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class Not found : br.org.test.MyClassTest
```

How can I fix this? Where should I put the jars for dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the jar file in `$CARBON_HOME/repository/components/extensions` directory and do not forget to restart the server after adding the library.

**Source:** [How to Add External Jar Libraries to WSO2 Carbon based Products.](http://wso2.org/library/knowledgebase/add-external-jar-libraries-wso2-carbon-based-products)

Answer (score 0):

After a long research i finally was able to solve this by putting my dependencies in /lib/runtimes/ext.

Following this documentation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS530/Configuring+Runtime+Environment